# rsyslog filter on authpriv facility in rsyslog.conf

Tags: log-files, syslog, rsyslog, filter, syntax

This has been addressed in other post(s), but I still can't get this to work properly.

I am trying to OMIT (discard) certain entries from being written to my " `/var/log/secure` ".

Namely, any line that contains certain trusted IP Addresses, in this example " `IP = 10.10.10.10` ".

From what I understand, using a REGEX expression like this should do the trick, but I think I have an issue with placement in the file:

```
if $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv' and $msg !contains '10.10.10.10' then /var/log/secure
    &~
```

Here's what I've tried so far in my `/etc/rsyslog.conf` file:

    #rsyslog v3 config file

```
# if you experience problems, check
# http://www.rsyslog.com/troubleshoot for assistance

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock.so    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog.so  # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#### RULES ####

if $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv' and $msg !contains '10.10.10.10' then /var/log/secure
&~

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none           /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                             /var/log/secure
```

*Another slight variation to the rsyslog.conf file would be as follows, as I've read the order in which this rule appears makes a difference:*

```
#rsyslog v3 config file

# if you experience problems, check
# http://www.rsyslog.com/troubleshoot for assistance

#### MODULES ####

$ModLoad imuxsock.so    # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog.so  # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####

# Use default timestamp format
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#### RULES ####

if $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv' and $msg !contains '10.10.10.10' then /var/log/secure
&~

# Log all kernel messages to the console.
# Logging much else clutters up the screen.
#kern.*                                                 /dev/console

# Log anything (except mail) of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none           /var/log/messages

# The authpriv file has restricted access.
authpriv.*                                             /var/log/secure
if $syslogfacility-text == 'authpriv' and $msg !contains '10.10.10.10' then /var/log/secure
&~
```

I have tried many other ways, but do not want to pollute this post with too many variations.

Another important point, is that I need to make sure that OTHER log files via `rsyslog` throughout the system STILL track this IP Address however.

So essentially, just OMIT any line that contains "`10.10.10.10`" from the " `/var/log/secure` "